# does using handler might speed up the data display?

Tags: android, concurrency, handler, android-handler

in the App i am developing, i have a a layout with 6 TextViews, these textviews wil display data received at very high rate from a server. so far, i set the 
values i receive to the textviews, but when i run the App. the data that textview displays are changing very slow because of the values sent at very high rate.

for an example, the server send almost 100 line in one second, and the datat in this 100 lines should be displayed by the TextViews..but because, as you noticed, 
the high rate at which the dtat is being sent, the TextViews cannot show all the data by the time they sent.

What i want to do is, to be able to display these frequent data using the textViews but without lagging or delay in display the data, something like how do you see
the sensor data displayedin a textView.

given the above issue, does using the handler might help?

Answer (score 1):

> given the above issue, does using the handler might help?

To answer your question, this is what the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) say in regards to `Handler`:

> There are two main uses for a Handler:
>   (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and
>   (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

Honnestly, I don't see how the Handler could help you achieve what you are looking for.
Do you make your http request in a separate thread? (if not, then you should)

Also, I am not sure I understood the connection between the `TextViews` and the `very high rate from server`.

Answer (score 0):

The handler is only a means of enqueuing a Runnable to be run in the Main Thread. You shouldn't plug the output of the server directly to the GUI, because you might be clogging up the main thread.
If you are downloading at high frequency, I'd suggest storing the downloaded data somewhere in memory (or persistence if needed), and have the GUI read this intermediate data at a slower pace.

Comment: "I'd suggest storing the downloaded data somewhere in memory (or persistence if needed), and have the GUI read this intermediate data at a slower pace."....the point is that, i need to dispay the datat to the textViews   at the same time the server published the data

Comment: But you can have a timer updating the GUI each second, for instance.